# angularjs isolated scope local property ''&" not triggering the function being passed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am facing the problem with one of my custom directives.I am passing a function from view(html) as the isolated scope local property(&) but the function doesn't get triggered/called. I have already tried one of the suggestions - which is to use object literal and pass it to the function that is getting triggered but that didn't worked.

My best guess is that it's the problem with the scope it check that the following function gets returned.
       function(locals) {
              return parentGet(scope, locals);
       };
And the scope here is referring to nested scope and the function I want to access/trigger is in parent scope.

How can I access the parent scope in this custom directive? Or is there a way to tackle this problem?

thanks

Comment: Without a code its difficult to figure out the root cause. Provide fiddle or plnkr.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg  Yeah I know its difficult to get an answer without code. It is a bit complicated but I have to do $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent to get to the parent controller method. There are many approaches suggested but nothing seems to be working so far.